# Issues understanding BNF grammar form

Tags: parsing, grammar, bnf

I am learning how BNF grammar works and I have been given the following example of some BNF grammar rules. I'm just trying to understand what this means and I'm having trouble:

```
  <S> ::=  ‘(‘ <A> ‘)’     
  <A> ::=  ‘[‘ <A> ‘]’              
      | <S> ‘{‘ <A> ‘}’
      | a | … | z
```

I don't understand what the brackets in quotations mean. And as far as I understood it this expression should be saying something like

```
S expanded = '(' <A> ')'.
A expanded = ‘[‘ <A> ‘]’              
          or <S> ‘{‘ <A> ‘}’
          or a or … or z
```

but I do not understand why A's expansion would have A inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The brackets in quotes in the `A` production here call for literal brackets in the input.

So a valid example of an `A` construct could be `[ z ]`.

As for your second point, the `A` rule is recursive, meaning that angle brackets may be infinitely nested in an `A` construct.